# How to iterate over a dictionary for Ansible's win_nssm module?

Tags: ansible

Ansible v2.10.x

I'm trying to use Ansible to start our Windows application services using `win_nssm`.
I want to use `win_nssm`. I have a dictionary that looks like this now (but ic can change based on the answer).

```
web_services:
  Web:
    description: "Web service"
    app_dir: "C:\\Myfolder\\Web"
    app_command: "app.js Web env=%NODE_ENVIRONMENT% port=8080 ssl_port=8443"
    dependency: ""
  PrintService:
    description: "Print service"
    app_dir: "C:\\Myfolder\\Web"
    app_command: "app_service.js SERVICE_NAME=PRINTSERVICE"
    dependency: "Web"
```

How can I iterate over the above dictionary for `win_nssm`?

```
- name: Create services
  win_nssm:
    name: "{{ the item key }}"
    app_parameters_free_form: "Description={{ item description value }}"
    application: "{{ item app_dir value }}/{{ item app_command value }}"
    dependency: "{{ item dependency value }}"
  loop: ????
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: The data is not [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/). How do you want to read it?

Comment: Your data structure does not make sense, (a dict which keys contain a list of single key dicts) and will be a pain to loop. Make this a simple list of dicts with all needed keys including the name. Or keep it as a dict and make the keys dicts themselves and use `dict2items` in the `loop` stanza.

Comment: Note: you need to escape the backslashes (`\\`) in your above code to make it a valid yaml. Meanwhile the structure will still not make sense as reported above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updated data structure, you could write something like this:

```
    - name: Create services
      win_nssm:
        name: "{{ item.0 }}"
        app_parameters_free_form: "Description={{ item.1.description }}"
        application: "{{ item.1.app_dir }}/{{ item.1.app_command }}"
        dependency: "{{ item.1.dependency }}"
      loop: "{{ web_services.items() }}"
```

The `.items()` method on a dictionary returns a list of `(key, value)`
pairs, so within the task, `item.0` (aka `item[0]`) is the key, and
`item.1` is the associated dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.